# How to design an algorithm to find covariance for multiple variables?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, bigdata

Below is the covariance equation for two variables, ABC and XYZ.

[image: covariance equation for two variables]

Below is the algorithm to find the covariance between ABC and XYZ.

```
Algorithm 1: Calculate Covariance
1. cov = 0
2. for i = 0 to size - 1
3.  cov = cov + (return_abc[i] - avg_abc) * (return_xyz[i] - avg_xyz)
4. end for
5. cov = cov / size - 1
6. end
```

How do I design an algorithm to find the covariance between one variable to the rest of the variables in a sample?
For example, how do I find the covariance between APPLE's stock and the rest of the stocks in NASDAQ (about 3,100 companies) ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.investopedia.com/articles/financial-theory/11/calculating-covariance.asp

If you're looking at only end of day prices (for simplicity), and you would like to compare a single stock to all of the rest of the stocks, try treating the rest of them all as one element, ie:

```
n=number of days to analyze
marketReturn = average(return of each stock that isn't APPLE)
marketAverage = (sum of marketReturn's)/n
appleAverage = (sum of APPLE returns)/n
```

then apply the summation across a sample size of the number of days you are analyzing.

```
Answer = (((day 1 APPLE return %)-(appleAverage))*((day 1 marketReturn %)-(marketAverage)) + ((day 2 APPLE return %)-(appleAverage))*((day 2 marketReturn %)-(marketAverage)) + ...)/(n-1)
```

I suppose if you want to check each stock individually:

```
for(x=0;x<numStocksNotAPPLE;++x)//increment through each stock
{
    covariantList[x]=(((day 1 APPLE return percent)-(appleAverage))*((day 1 stock[x] percent)-(stock[x] average)) + ... + (((day n APPLE return %)-(appleAverage))*((day n stock[x] %)-(stock[x] average)))/(n-1)
}//that should give you a covariant APPLE vs each stock
```

and then if you want just one number, you could take the average of the covariantList:

```
foreach(covariantList c)
{
    sum+=c
}

averageCovariant = sum/covariantList.size
```

Keep in mind this is all psuedo-code, i'm not claiming any of it is functional

Comment: What if I want to compare a single stock to the rest of the stocks individually. I do not want to treat them as one element ? How should I design the algorithm ?